# My Cypher query returns double values when I exectue a query te get a couple of nodes with all relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My intention is to get a certain amount of field from my graph and all concerning relationships. The problem with the following query is that it returns some of the values twice. My question is what am I doing wrong here?

```
MATCH (v:V) 
WHERE v.label = "myLabel" 
OR v.label = "someLabel"
OR v.label = "anotherLabel"
MATCH (v)<-[bv:BEVAT_IETS]-(com:Com)
WITH com, COLLECT(bv) AS bevatIets, v
MATCH (v)<-[iv:I_V]-(vi:VI)
WITH vi, COLLECT(iv) AS ivlijst, bevatIets, com, v
MATCH (irv)<-[vrv:V_R_V]-(v)<-[vrn:V_R_N]-(irn)
WITH vi, ivlijst, bevatIets, com, COLLECT(vrn) AS vrns, vrn, v, 
     COLLECT(vrv) AS vrvs, vrv
return v, com, bevatIets, ivLijst, vi,
       vrns, vrn, vrvs, vrv
```

Comment: oke what value do you mean? Also some drawing of your structure would be better so i can see the structure of the graph. vriendelijke groeten.

Comment: Sorry. my problem is concerning all the relationship values.

Comment: It would be super helpful if you could write your query in terms that makes sense. Right now it only makes my eyes hurt and my brain go mushy :)

Comment: I have but the names are classified

Answer (score 0):

The following (somewhat simplified) query should solve at least some of the duplicates.

```
MATCH (v:V)<-[bv:BEVAT_IETS]-(com:Com)
WHERE v.label IN ["myLabel", "someLabel", "anotherLabel"]
WITH com, COLLECT(bv) AS bevatIets, v
MATCH (v)<-[iv:I_V]-(vi:VI)
WITH vi, COLLECT(iv) AS ivlijst, bevatIets, com, v
MATCH (irv)<-[vrv:V_R_V]-(v)<-[vrn:V_R_N]-(irn)
RETURN v, com, bevatIets, ivLijst, vi,
       COLLECT(vrn) AS vrns, COLLECT(vrv) AS vrvs;
```

The main problem that I saw with your original query is that its last `WITH` clause contained these values:

```
COLLECT(vrn) AS vrns, vrn
COLLECT(vrv) AS vrvs, vrv
```

It does not make any sense, for example, to attempt to "collect all `vrn` values for each `vrn` value" -- which is what `COLLECT(vrn) AS vrns, vrn` means. Each collection would end up only containing a single value.

By getting rid of the `vrn` and `vrv` terms, you allow the collections to actually aggregate values, as you intended. This should reduce (and perhaps eliminate entirely) all the duplicate data you have been seeing.